# tsc does not recognize '--init' option

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, tsc

For some reason `npx tsc --init` prints out the following error:

```
$ npx tsc --init
npx: installed 1 in 1.467s
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'init'.
```

I have installed the `typescript` package with **Yarn 2**:

```
$ yarn add -D typescript
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0.31s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ typescript@npm:3.9.3 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ typescript@patch:typescript@npm%3A3.9.3#builtin<compat/typescript>::version=3.9.3&hash=8cac75 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the disk
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1.46s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: Done in 1.95s
```

Can someone explain to me why `tsc` does not recognize `--init` and what i am doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**:

As [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62077033/6904888) figured out, the problem is that `npx` does not find or recognize the `typescript` package installed with **Yarn 2**. The solution was to use `yarn` instead: `yarn tsc --init`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Judging from the output of `npx tsc --init` you do not seem to have the `typescript` package installed in the directory where you've run the command. `npx` tries to be helpful by installing any packages needed in order for the command to run.

Although it was trying to be helpful it ended up not installing the package one would expect in 2020. If you run `$ npx tsc -v` you will most likely get this output:

```
$ npx tsc -v
npx: installed 1 in 1.098s
message TS6029: Version 1.5.3
```

If you had the `typescript` package installed, however, you would have gotten this, instead:

```
$ npx tsc -v
Version 3.9.3
```

As you can see, the version installed by `npm` is different. That's because `npx` ended up installing the `tsc` package **and not `typescript`**. The `tsc` package also provides a `tsc` command. `npx` chose it instead of `typescript` because, while both packages provide a `tsc` command, it is also called `tsc`. `npx` thought it was a better fit.

**UPDATE:**

Yarn 2 introduces the `Plug'n'Play` feature. Dependencies are installed very differently from how Yarn 1 and `npm` used to.

Yarn 1 and `npm` place the code for your packages in the `node_modules` directory in every single project. `npx` goes to look for commands there.

Yarn 2, on the other hand, installs package code in a shared location and places in your project a single `.pnp.js` file that performs the mapping. If you install a package for one project, you won't have to download it again if you use it in another project.

Any tooling that was dependent on `node_modules`, however, will be broken. That's why `npx` was unable to find `typescript` in your project. `npx` does not know about `Plug'n'Play`.

You can read more about this feature here: https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp

Comment: While this seems to be true, isn't `yarn` supposed to install the `typescript` package in a directory where npx can find it? According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) npx also checks `$PATH`. Since `yarn` is designed as an alternative to npm and it's also in `$PATH`, shouldn't it work right away? Btw, I installed yarn 2 like recommendet in the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)

Comment: Yarn 2? That's the missing piece of the puzzle. I've updated the answer.

Comment: yeah.. I forgot to mention that in my initial post.. -.- 
By the way, thanks!

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I understood the explanation, but not mixing yarn and npm helped in my case, so `yarn add -D typescript && yarn tsc --init` ...

Answer (score 6):

For others came here which use no `yarn` nor `npx`, in my case that solve it:

```
npm install -g typescript --force
```

**EDIT**

1. I know it doesn't answer the exact question, but it does handle same error.
2. Possible explanation of my `npm` solution: something was broken before, maybe installed `tsc` instead of `typescript`, or problems with previous `typescript` installation itself.
   `npm install` would install typescript again, and `--force` flag is for ignoring existing local files and override them.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand why this is a good solution and what exactly the force option does here.